# How to fix CORS using HandleCors in Laravel 10, look like it not work?

Tags: laravel, next.js, cors, laravel-10

I am using Laravel 10 and I added the class `\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class` in the Kernel file as shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EalEs.png). However, I'm still getting the error `has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`.

My backend is located on a subdomain `be.domain.net`, while the frontend is on `domain.net`. Here is my cors config file as seen in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtP2R.png).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have not set the value

> SESSION_DOMAIN = .domain.net

in the .env file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).